# defer mutex.Unlock() in golang sometimes never called

Tags: go, concurrency, defer-keyword

Code is rewritten to be less confusing so I hope it makes sense (and that I haven't removed the problem by rewritten the code). The issue is that sometimes a `defer Mutex.Unlock()` never happens making the lists locked forever, explained below

I have a list of `OuterStruct` where each item contains a list of `InnerInt`. Both of these lists can change concurrently by things happening. In our case, if a websocket connection goes down or comes up.

I have a function that returns some of the data from each `OuterStruct`, including the int values for all the `InnerInt` objects for every `OuterStruct`. So, since both of these lists can be modified concurrently I use Mutex on both of them. So first, I lock the "outer" list and do `defer outerStructList.Mutex.Unlock()`. Then I iterate the outer list and for each element I run `(outer *OuterStruct) getInnerInts()`. This function will do a `Mutex.Lock()` on the inner list. Iterate that list, get all the actual int values and return an array of those ints. The outer fucntion will set that array to on of the fields of the returning object plus another field and then iterate to the next object.

What happens sometimes is that the Unlock() on the inner list **never** happens. Even though I use `defer outer.InnerInts.Mutex.Unlock()`. The only thing shuold happen after that is that I iterate the elements and add the int value to an array of ints, then the array is returned at which point I assume the `Unlock` should occur.

I am aware of that I could probably improve this code quite a bit but does anyone have any idea why the inner Mutex could sometimes never unlock? What could possibly happen between the `Lock()` and the functionality of the function (iterating the array) to result in the function never returning and therefore Mutex never unlocking?

```
func getAllOuterStructs() []int {
    outerStructsList.Mutex.Lock()
    defer outerStructsList.Mutex.Unlock()
    var returnOuterStructsToSend []OuterStructToSend
    for _, rangedOuterStruct := range outerStructsList {
        outerStructToSend := OuterStructToSend{}
        outerStructToSend.OtherValue := rangedOuterStruct.OtherValue
        outerStructToSend.IntList := rangedOuterStruct.getInnerInts()
        returnOuterStructsToSend = append(returnOuterStructsToSend, outerStructToSend)
    }

    return returnOuterStructsToSend
}
```

```
func (outer *OuterStruct) getInnerInts() []int {
    outer.InnerInts.Mutex.Lock()
    defer outer.InnerInts.Mutex.Unlock()
    outerInts := outer.InnerInts
    var returnInts []int
    for _, rangedInt := range outerInts {
        returnInts = append(returnInts, rangedInt.IntVal)
    }

    return returnInts
}
```

Comment: When nesting mutexes, the usual explanation is that another part of your code is attempting to grab mutexes in a different order. You should also show your various types in use. Reminder: don't copy a mutex.

Comment: I know that nothing else is trying to grab the mutex. I do however copy it on occasion, mostly when logging. But should look into that more